# Any online tool that highlights what grammatical case each word in a sentence belongs to?

Tags: grammar, morphology, grammatical-case, learning, online-resources

I'm absolutely confused when it comes to cases in English, and more so when I'm studying other languages (leisurely). I've tried to learn cases at least three times in my life and every time it just slips my mind because it's so confusing for me.

Is there any online tool (probably using AI) that highlights the case of each word in a sentence/string? If there truly isn't, what online learning resource can you recommend for me to learn cases (in all languages) as efficiently as possible?

Even better, can someone give a succinct introductory overview here?

Comment: Is grammatical case the same as part of speech?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: There are tools for part of speech tagging (noun, verb, etc) if you Google or search here (though not totally reliable or easy to use). English doesn't have much in the way of cases except for pronouns so I'm not aware of tools for that. Are you actually interested in grammatical case (subjective, objective, dative) or semantic function (agent, patient, instrument...)?

Comment: English has no cases. Cases are nominative, dative, ablative and so forth.

Comment: @StuartF I'm not so sure. I want to learn what every case on this Wikipedia list means. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_grammatical_cases The list itself does not give great examples and Google is no help either.

Comment: @Lambie Can you clarify? Do you mean that cases aren't determined by prefixes or suffixes? My question doesn't just apply to English, I want to learn grammatical cases so I can better understand other languages like Russian or Persian that do have case suffixes

Comment: I am telling you again: English does not have cases. Cases refer  to the suffix inflections of nouns in languages. Here is an example of first-declension nouns in Latin. Look at the endings in the chart. Those are appended to the noun. https://booksnbackpacks.com/latin-cases-for-beginners/ Cases are different in all languages. You are ,misusing the term. And in nouns: the change the meanings. For the boy, of the boy, the boy, to the boy.

Comment: As expected according to your link, cases apply to "various inflectional languages that have declension." Not English. We use other words and context to convey that meaning. We use 'raise' to show when we *cause a rise*, not a causative tense. We use He/Him/His for other functions. Maybe you mean something other than case?

Comment: @YosefBaskin No, what I meant was an online tool (that probably uses machine learning technology) that highlights each word a different colour representing their grammatical case. And in the case of English (pun intended), it would need to scan the context of the given string in order to know each word's grammatical case. So for example, if red were to represent nominative case, and blue were to represent accusative case, then the sentence "He ate the apple" would have "He" highlighted in red and "apple" highlighted in blue, and the rest of the words as some case I don't know about yet.

Comment: In "He ate the apple", "apple" isn't accusative or objective case, it's just a regular unmarked noun. There seems some dispute over whether English pronouns have cases or inflectional forms, but it's reasonable to say "he" is nominative (aka subjective). In contrast, it's presumably possible to create a tool for Russian or Latin that would tell you which of the 6 or so cases each noun was in, and if you know or want to learn those languages, it would be interesting and maybe useful (although some languages case-mark articles not nouns). But that's off-topic for an English language group.

Comment: It sounds to me as if @printerprinter1555 is asking for a tool which will analyse a sentence and report the grammatical relations that each nominal was involved in, as these are what would be expressed by case markings in inflectional languages. This is presumably possible in principle, and any translation tools that are analytic rather than heuristic must be doing it. I don't know anything about what tools there actually are.

Answer (score 4):

Hi printerprinter1555,

I am going to follow conventions from the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (if needed, [this](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/overview.html) gives you an overview, section 7 is most relevant for you) in this post. Please bear in mind that there are various accepted ways of analyzing the English Language.

As the Modern English language is quite [analytic](https://www.britannica.com/topic/analytic-language) in nature, it does not have a very elaborate case system anymore. Whereas [Old English nouns had four to five different cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_grammar#Case), in Modern English there are only two cases for **nouns**:
The genetive (most commonly used to indicate posession or some kind of belonging, easy to identify because it has the *'s* or *s'* ending) and the plain case (used for everything else).

English **personal pronouns** have five different inflectional forms:

1. nominative (e.g. *I, she, we*)
2. accusative (e.g. *me, her, us*)
3. dependent genitive (e.g. *my, her, our*)
4. independent genitive (e.g. *mine, hers, ours*)
5. reflexive (e.g. *myself, herself, ourselves*)

I think it would be sufficient to keep in mind that nouns are always in plain case unless they have the genitive marker *'s* or *s'*, and to memorize the different cases for each personal pronoun. So at least for English, there is no need for an automatic classifier. However, I suspect that you might be interested in syntax trees and the different levels of language analysis (esp. syntax and morphology).

Concerning the [Wikipedia page about cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_grammatical_cases) you gave in a comment to the original question, I think I should clarify that the examples given in the "Example" column would be better described as "illustrations" or "paraphrases". They are multi-word translations of circumstances that can be expressed by just one word in the respective case of the origin language (the origin language is indicated in the "Found in" column). In English, a paraphrase is needed because the language does not have these special cases, so a single-world translation is not possible.

Comment: I was about to CV this question as not fitting the ELU template. But this frame-challenge answer is very important and useful.