Is “we” used correctly in following sentence?
Is the following sentence proper usage of “we”?

The elk and bison are not bothered by we humans and vehicles.

I would have written it,

The elk and bison are not bothered by humans or vehicles.


by being a preposition mandates objective case of the pronoun: hence us.

Does this answer your question? “A threat to us people” or “a threat to we people”?  << The first version is grammatical in today's standard English. The second version seems to be ungrammatical (that is, unacceptable), because the word "we" is in nominative case instead of the expected accusative case.... In your [first] version, the word "us" is a personal determinative. >> [F.E.] // Obviously, the scope of determiner/determinative 'us' does not extend to 'vehicles' here. But do use 'or'.

@Lambie We don't have cases in English? Who told you that? Please feel free to enlighten me on this. By the way, are you a grammarian or a self-styled grammar cop?

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/597062/any-online-tool-that-highlights-what-grammatical-case-each-word-in-a-sentence-be cases are nominative, dative, ablative, accusative, vocative  etc. in languages with declensions like Greek and Latin. English no longer has cases.

@Lambie Thanks for the link. So basically what we call cases in traditional grammar are called inflectional forms in modern grammar? Is that the whole story or is there more to it? I'm more than happy to be taught things I don't know.

@user405662 Yes, grammarians say English is no longer an inflectional language, meaning modern English doesn't have cases per se.

Thanks everyone for your input.  I read that first sentence earlier today and it has been bothering me all day.
